# Analyzing a 1-mutable-register instruction set?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, boolean, logic

## Summary of problem

I need to be able to generate instructions for a conceptual CPU + instruction set. I have an almost-working algorithm.

The CPU only has 1 mutable register (named mut) which always begins as 1, and some amount of immutable registers with values in them (named input[0..n]). The instructions for this CPU are just logical gates on mut with one of the input registers that store the result back into mut.

I need an algorithm to generate the instructions that will allow this CPU to generate the correct answer for each possible set of inputs from some defined truth-table.

## Example

As an example, maybe I want this CPU to act like an AND gate (which has a truth table of `00=0,01=0,10=0,11=1`). I should be able to feed the algorithm this truth-table and have it spit out the instructions "`AND[0] AND[1]`". If you follow with your head, you can see that MUT will only remain 1 if both INPUT[0] and INPUT[1] are 1.

## Attempt

Currently, I have a naive implementation of an algorithm that simply does a breadth-first search of all possible sets of instructions, testing each them on each of the truth-table input/output pairs to see if it works. For a lot of the expectations I feed the algorithm, it returns the correct set of instructions in just a few levels of search. However, for others, it will consume my entire CPU's memory before it finds a result, so I can only assume it can't find a result.

## Questions

Is there a) any efficient way to design this algorithm, b) any way to prove that, for a certain instruction set, any expected truth-table can be achieved or c) any existing insights into this problem?

I know of Karnaugh maps, but they generate 2D logic circuits, whereas this is essentially a 1D logic circuit.

If you have any questions please let me know. It's a difficult problem to explain but I really need help on it.

## Instruction Set

For reference, the instructions I have are:

```
AND[n]: MUT = MUT & INPUT[n]
OR[n]: MUT = MUT | INPUT[n]
NOT: MUT = ~MUT
```

I might be able to more instructions to the CPU, but ideally the algorithm could attempt to solve the problem with any given instruction set.

Comment: What instructions do you have available?  For example, do you have a conditional branch instruction?

Comment: We will need to know a little more about the CPU instruction set. What operations can it natively perform? "just logical gates" is not enough information. I see that instructions are of the form mut <- mut <opr> reg[i] but what is the set of <opr> available?

Comment: The instructions are strictly linear- Once started, it runs through the instructions with no branching available. I'll edit the topic with the "instruction set".

Comment: How big is MUT in bits? 1 bit?  Unbounded size?

Comment: Sorry, shoulda mentioned that, it's all just booleans.

Comment: Since all these logic gates take two inputs, then for each type of gate, there shall be only 4 entries to check (00,01,10,11). Why are you checking others? Those shall only be repetitions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The individual logic gates will only take 2 inputs, but the instructions will essentially create a new, custom logic gate out of those basic ones (the instruction set). It's basically a selector, but programmed as a series of instructions... So I could tell it "make me a set of instructions that will, given 000 return 1, given 001 return 0, given 010 return 0, given 011 return 1, given 100 return 0 ..." and it would give me a series of instructions I could perform using each of those 3 inputs that will return what I want.

Comment: Addition is not possible using bitwise operations without shifting. To check if all possible logic tables are possible you have to check the 16 possibilities. If you have a NOT instruction you only have to check 8 possibilities. I checked that a combination of NOT, AND, OR and XOR will work without reading an input twice. Without having a second MUT register you cannot get rid of the XOR instruction.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I agree. I think the second MUT could be a pure accumulator (let's call it ACC), and OP would need to add one more instruction which would add (or) the MUT to the ACC and then bring the MUT back to its initial state (1): "ACC <- ACC | MUT, MUT <- 1".

Comment: @MartinRosenau is correct. In general, without intermediate storage locations, you cannot evaluate expressions that have parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Martin Rosenau, and I doubt that your CPU can process any given truth table without additional funcionality. As you have it now, I can't see how to implement e.g. XOR.

Hence, I took the liberty to add an accumulator regitser ACC (which will be initialized to False) and an additional command `ACC` which does:

```
ACC <- ACC or MUT
MUT <- True
```

Given this, the following routine takes a parameter `rules` which is a list of lists of bools, each line indicating first the result and then the input registers 0..n of the truth table. For instance dyadic XOR would be `[[True, True, True], [False, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, False]]`.

This hopefully generates the correct instructions:

```
def generateCode (rules):
    rules = [rule for rule in rules if rule [0] ]
    if not rules: return []
    opcodes = []
    for rule in rules:
        rule = rule [1:]
        negs = [i for i, e in enumerate (rule) if not e]
        poss = [i for i, e in enumerate (rule) if e]
        if negs:
            opcodes.append ('NOT')
            for neg in negs: opcodes.append ('OR[{}]'.format (neg) )
            opcodes.append ('NOT')
        if poss:
            for pos in poss: opcodes.append ('AND[{}]'.format (pos) )
        opcodes.append ('ACC')
    return opcodes
```

For example, taken the sample input from above this gives `['AND[0]', 'AND[1]', 'ACC', 'NOT', 'OR[0]', 'OR[1]', 'NOT', 'ACC']`, which seems to be correct.

This is the CPU I have tested it with. I have added a reset button and the result will be in ACC at the end of execution.

```
class CPU:
    def reset (self, inputs):
        self.MUT = True
        self.ACC = False
        self.INP = inputs [:]

    def __call__ (self, opcodes):
        for opcode in opcodes:
            if opcode == 'NOT':
                self.MUT = not self.MUT
                continue
            if opcode == 'ACC':
                self.ACC = self.ACC or self.MUT
                self.MUT = True
                continue
            if opcode [0] == 'O':
                inp = int (opcode [3:-1] )
                self.MUT = self.MUT or self.INP [inp]
                continue
            if opcode [0] == 'A':
                inp = int (opcode [4:-1] )
                self.MUT = self.MUT and self.INP [inp]
                continue
            raise Exception ('Need more dried frog pills.')
        return self.ACC
```

Again, I am sorry that I couldn't answer your question with the restrictions you specified, but hopefully my snippet is of some use to you.

Comment: First, I must truly commend you for such a great response. :)

Comment: I see what you're doing now... For every truth, you check if the inputs match that truth condition, and if so return True. To check that, you take the (assumed to be True) value of MUT and AND it with all the expected-to-be-True inputs, then you flip MUT, and OR it with all the expected-to-be-False inputs. Then you store it into ACC. You've basically split up the operation into checking if the inputs match any of the inputs that should return True, and if so, setting ACC permanently to True.

It's a simple approach and very clever. However, a few questions...

Comment: The problem without the ACC is the following: Expressions like `(a or b) and (c or d)` or `(a and b) or (c and d)` need to operate on the results of the parentheses and we have nowhere to store them. And we can't get rid of the parentheses either.

Comment: a) It seems that, for truth tables with more False outputs, you could flip how ACC works and end up with a much smaller set of instructions, right? b) I was hoping for an optimal approach. Any thoughts on making this return the fewest instructions possible? and c) Any thoughts, at all, on not adding an ACC register? It's possible in my problem domain but I want to reach for a solution that doesn't have an ACC. Is there a formal proof for it?

Comment: a) and b) You are right, the result is not minimal. I am not even sure if it is smarter to try to minimize the boolean input term or to take the non-optimal code and try to minimize that... As for c: Without an ACC, I wouldn't know how to implement `(inp0 or inp1) and (inp2 or inp3)`. You can't get rid of the parentheses and you have nowhere to store intermediate results. This is just a conjecture, I thankfully left behind formal proofs when I got my degree.

Comment: In that case, could an additional OP prevent the need for an ACC? Looking at your example, could `(inp0 or inp1) and (inp2 or inp3)` be turned into a non-nested expression with xor?

Comment: @DanRedux I personally don't see any means how to get rid of the accumulator. But you could ask this on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DanRedux Even in ANF (or Zhegalkin polynomial) which uses XOR the problem persists: It xor's a lot of conjunctions and where do you store the intermediate results of theses conjunctions.